# Filtering dataframe and making files from columns

Tags: python, pandas

My data frame looks like this-

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'zone':['AA','CC','AA','CC','AA','CC'],'val':[22,14,32,76,9,14],'date':[   4/01/2020,  4/01/2020,  4/02/2020,  4/02/2020,  4/03/2020,  4/03/2020]})
```

Now I want to filter out the zones and make separate files with the corresponding date and val column .
I tried doing this-

```
d = {k:list(x) for k,x in df.groupby('zone')['val']}
```

which produces the output-

```
  { 'AA': [array(22,32,9)]
    'CC': [array(14,76,14)]
  }
```

but I am not able to figure out how to go from here to the final output.

Final Output:

Filename: 'AA'

```
date          val
4/01/2020     22
4/02/2020     32
4/03/2020     9
```

Filename: 'CC'

```
date          val
4/01/2020     14
4/02/2020     76
4/03/2020     14
```

Comment: Why don't you do `AA= df[df['zone']=='AA']]` . Is that you have too many categories that you do not want to do it manually like this?

Comment: @XXavier In the actual dataset there are a lot of zones running in the 100s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix your code

```
d = {k:x.drop('zone',1) for k,x in df.groupby('zone')}
```

Update

```
for i,j in df.groupby('zone'):
    j.drop('zone',1).to_csv(i+'.csv')
```

Comment: How does it fix ? i ran it and this is the output-

Comment: {'AA':    val       date
 0   22  4/01/2020
 2   32  4/02/2020
 4    9  4/03/2020, 'CC':    val       date
 1   14  4/01/2020
 3   76  4/02/2020
 5   14  4/03/2020}

Comment: @ubuntu_noob try d['AA']

Comment: I wanted a more general answer since the actual dataset is huge

Comment: So you want a dataframe name as AA and CC ?

Comment: I wanted the final output as files.. i have written the final output in the question

Comment: csv file has the zone column also..how to remove that part from csv?

Comment: @ubuntu_noob add drop ~